# multiuser application managing back stack of each user

Tags: android

everybody

I work on multiuser application, which is REST client, so when you launch it, the 1st activity you see is LoginActivity.

For example, I have ten activities and LoginActivity and I can navigate e.g. next way:
LoginActivity -> Activity1 -> Activity3 -> Activity8(logout) -> LoginActivity.
I can do log out from every activity.

Possible next situation:

1) user1 logged in: LoginActivity -> Activity1 -> .. **Activity7(logout)** -> 
LoginActivity.

2) user2 logged in: LoginActivity -> Activity1 -> .. Activity4(logout) -> LoginActivity.

3) user1 logging in again: LoginActivity -> **Activity7**..
and user1 must *naturally* go to Activity7 with his last back stack if possible.

Also user must see only relevant for him data.

Is there any mechanisms to manage all this stuff?
I mean, does android platform support such multiuser apps, or restoring/storing back stack manually.

Any other ideas?

p.s. I found workaround to use SharedPrefences for each user to store only *his* data and store activity he logged in from. But it seems not *android way* as for me.

**UPD:** I done some research, and found out two intent flags to launch new 
task with it`s back stack history: 
(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK  |  FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK)

So, as I understand, in case of above example LoginActivity is 
something like "top level launcher" mention in javadoc of 
FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK.

But, I cannot find docs/sample of top level launcher; how to manage 
tasks by their IDs. 
Please help with top level launcher sample or managing tasks api.

**UPD2:** I found how some functions how to manipulate tasks by task id:

public void moveTaskToFront (int taskId, int flags); 

but it is only since API level 11
But I use level 7, is there any technique how to move task to foreground?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way of managing tasks since "it isn't really how `tasks` are supposed to work. The whole point of them is that they are entirely separate, unrelated things"
I solved a similar problem inspired in this [solution](http://ericharlow.blogspot.com/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html) although. In this solution, you keep track of the `activities` being used, so it suits your idea, I think. I don't think you will be using a tab system, so discard the bottom part. The important part is the `ActivityGroup` management.

I hope this helps.